# String value instead of integer in combobox value member vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, valuemember

I have looked up .ValueMember and have figured out it can only accept integers I assume. My question is if my league column returns ABC can that be both the Display name and the value of the combobox some how? If so any help to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.;Database=database;Uid=username;Pwd=password;")

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT league FROM league_names ORDER BY league ASC", con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)

    'Display table data in combobox
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "league"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "league"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code that worked for me. I just added all the mysql data into a DataGridView then use a for each loop to get the names.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.;Database=database;Uid=username;Pwd=password;")

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT league FROM league_names ORDER BY league ASC", con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```